Running `ps -t /dev/<tty>` started causing the specified terminal to stop receiving most keystrokes
Specific Problem
Running ps -t /dev/<tty> recently started causing the associated terminal to stop receiving some keystrokes. I can't fathom why this started happening now, without any software updates that I'm aware of.
After running the ps command, most keystrokes will no longer make it through to this shell or whatever program is running in the tty (e.g. if you run it from in a vim subshell). Only a subset make it through, requiring repeating keypresses several times before they register, as if eaten by another process. Repeated runs of ps -t <tty> exacerbate the problem further.
To Reproduce
Notably, I can only reproduce this on one of my machines.
ps -t $(tty)

A significant percentage of keystrokes are dropped from the TTY now.
It can be run on the current TTY or another TTY. The target TTY is affected.
To recover from this, exit the TTY using Ctrl+D or exit. (Keystrokes will need to be entered repeatedly.)
I'd be interested to hear who can and cannot reproduce this.
Why This is Needed
vim-tmux-navigator uses this tmux configuration to detect whether vim is the active process in the current tmux pane, in order to allow seamless navigation within and between vim splits and tmux panes.
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' | \
        grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|l?n?vim?x?|fzf)(diff)?$'"
bind-key -n M-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-h"  "select-pane -L"
bind-key -n M-j if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-j"  "select-pane -D"
bind-key -n M-k if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-k"  "select-pane -U"
bind-key -n M-l if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-l"  "select-pane -R"

Versions
I'm running MacOS 14.6.1.
The /bin/ps executable hasn't been touched in a few months, and this has been working since.
❯ ls -l `which ps`
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  170816 Aug  4 06:31 /bin/ps

I haven't updated anything else that I know of since this was last working.
Further weirdness
After a tty starts losing keystrokes, if it is killed via tmux :kill-window rather than exiting normally, then other things start hanging until reboot:

brew (which is run to check openssl version during bashrc run) sometimes starts hanging and cannot be killed with ^C or stopped with ^Z until after rebooting, which blocks new terminals from starting.
sudo dmesg hangs and cannot be killed with ^C or stopped with ^Z until after rebooting.
ps -ef outputs some processes but then hangs. Unlike the others, it can be killed with ^C.

Related GitHub issue

I can't reproduce. I tried in both bash and zsh.

Losing keystrokes usually means there are multiple processes reading from the terminal at the same time, they each get different keystrokes.

I also have another MacBook on which I cannot reproduce this.

What output do you see from the ps command?

@Barmar
It outputs like you'd expect, listing 3 pids (for a new shell): login -fqp nilbus, -bash, and ps -t /dev/ttys019.

I have this issue too, and I noticed that for each invocation of ps -t, the Crowdstrike Falcon Agent opens a new fd on that tty. That would explain why it started happening all of a sudden, it's not ps itself, it's a Crowdstrike update. We all know how well those are tested. Also confirms your suspicion @Barmar, it's indeed another process reading the try. That's also why it doesn't affect everyone, just those with Crowdstrike.

Great find! I also have Crowdstrike agent installed. A co-worker confirmed that force-quitting the com.crowdstrike.falcon.Agent process temporarily resolves the issues with hanging (though the agent starts back up immediately after). Thank you! My company will be reaching out to Crowdstrike, and I recommend that you do too.
